# Stream to string

Tags: c#, string, stream

How do I append Stream output to a string instead of a file in this code?

```
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\temp\tmp.html"))                   
using (Stream input = res.GetResponseStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    input.Close();
    output.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

using (Stream input = res.GetResponseStream())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(input))
{
    string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Note this would read the entire `string` into memory.

Comment: OK, works. thanks! I should use Dispose() to clear the Streamreader afterwards, right?

Comment: @Rado Yes, you should. But my answer already wraps it in a `using` statement, which will call `Dispose` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use encoding to get a string and then use StringReader to read buffer.

```css
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

            using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\temp\tmp.html"))
            using (Stream input = res.GetResponseStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                input.Close();
                output.Close();

                string sBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(sBuffer);
​
```

Comment: OK, is this better than the first example? The original code is not using encoding and it works OK for the purpose (data scraping).